# mix two uneven lists with fill requirements

Tags: python

I’m mixing two lists in Python and while I know there are similar questions, I need to handle it in a certain way.

I have two lists and they may or may not be the same length. I need to interweave the two and use filler for the shorter list but the filler has to come before any of the values in the shorter list.

This is what I currently have:

```
def mix(a, b):
    fill='spam'
    if len(a) > len(b):
        d = len(a) - len(b)
        while d:
            b.insert(0, fill)
            d-=1
    if len(a) < len(b):
        d = len(b) - len(a)
        while d:
            a.insert(0, fill)
            d-=1

    n = zip(a, b)
    mixed = [item for sub in n for item in sub]
    return mixed
```

example:

```
>>> mix([1, 2 ,3], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
['spam', 'A', 'spam', 'B', 'spam', 'C', 1, 'D', 2, 'E', 3, 'F']
```

So the code works but it doesn’t seem like a good way to do it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of slicing when you want to paste one element over two in a list.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
In [39]: l1 = [1,2,3]
    ...: l2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
    ...: fill = 'spam'
    ...: 

In [40]: l = 2 * max(len(l1), len(l2))  # final length
    ...: mixed = [fill] * l  # result is initialized with the filler
    ...: mixed[l-2*len(l1)::2] = l1  # paste l1
    ...: mixed[l-2*len(l2)+1::2] = l2  # paste l2
    ...: mixed
    ...: 
Out[40]: ['spam', 'A', 'spam', 'B', 'spam', 'C', 1, 'D', 2, 'E', 3, 'F']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools


def mix(a, b):
    diff = len(a) - len(b)
    fill = 'spam'
    if diff > 0:
        b = [fill] * diff + b
    elif diff < 0:
        a = [fill] * abs(diff) + a
    return list(itertools.chain(*zip(a, b)))
```

You may have heard that Python has batteries included, i.e. it has may inbuilt utilities/features which helps in making a program simpler and more readable. The above function has two main differences from the original one:

- **Use of list multiplication and addition**: In Python a list can be added with another list and can be multiplied with a integer.

Eg:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] + ['a', 'b']
>>> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']


>>> [1] * 3
>>> [1, 1, 1]
>>> [1, 2] * 2
>>> [1, 2, 1, 2]
```

- `itertools.chain` **function**: This function simply chains the a list (not python list) of iterators/iterates provided to it as arguments into a single iterator.

Eg:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, the answer would be much more helpful if you could explain what the code is doing and why this is the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say that this is a better way to do it, but it does take advantage of a tool (itertools.izip_longest) in the Python Standard Library that is designed to handle zipping unequal length lists by filling with a default element.

```
import itertools

def mix(a, b):
    a_rev = reversed(a)
    b_rev = reversed(b)
    if len(a) > len(b):
        temp = itertools.izip_longest(a_rev, b_rev, fillvalue='spam')
    elif len(b) > len(a):
        temp = itertools.izip_longest(b_rev, a_rev, fillvalue='spam')      
    sequence = list()
    for item in temp:
    sequence.extend(item)
    return sequence

o = mix([1, 2 ,3], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
o.reverse()
print(o)
```